# Cut last char of stacktrace string

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I'm facing a problem in VS19 with .Net Framework 4.8.

I want to get the line number of the stack trace string and wrote following code:

```
linenum = Convert.ToInt32(e.StackTrace.Substring(e.StackTrace.LastIndexOf(":Zeile ") + 6));
```

I get this string, which can not be converted to Int32 because of the character '.' at the end.

> [image: Blockquote]

I tried to debug it with the follwing code:

```
string text = e.StackTrace.Substring(e.StackTrace.LastIndexOf(":Zeile") + 6);
int textlengh= text.Length;
```

Following output:

[image]

My questions is now, how can I remove the '.' character from this string.

Comment: `string.Replace(".", "");`

Comment: Thanks thats what I was searching for.

Comment: This will replace all the dots in the string. `TrimEnd('.').TrimStart(' ')` can address the problem - pinpoint.